# How do I find the amount of time a certain word appears in a title in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, sql-like

**You have a database with a lot of movies and their specific titles, the question is as follows.**

How many movies are there that have the word ‘love’ anywhere in the title? (Hint: The L in the word love can be upper or lower case and can be included in words such as ‘lovers’.)

This is my code thus far but I am not sure how to include the search for 'L' and 'Lovers'.

```
SELECT title
FROM Movies
WHERE title LIKE '%love%'
AND title LIKE 'love%'
OR title LIKE '%love'
```

**Can anyone assist?**

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support case-insensitive strings by default, so this would find all of them:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%love%'
```

Some don't.  A convenient function is to put the title in lower case:

```
WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%love%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`%love%` will also match foxglove, rollover, sloven, pullover etc. You should also review your AND/OR use in the WHERE clause to get the expected results. Having said that, your `'%love%' AND 'love%'` is the same as just `%love%` since `%` matches nothing as well as anything.

You may get better results matching `'% love%' OR 'love%'` which will give (titles where love% is not the first word) AND (titles where love% is the first word). Use `LOWER` or `UPPER` as suggested by Gordon to make the search case insensitive:

`WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE '% LOVE%' OR UPPER(title) LIKE 'LOVE%'`